# Gmod Lua Coding - How to place an HTML5 Page (Website) Inside of a Box

Tags: html, lua, web, box, garrys-mod

I've been working with a friend and we both have a problem, in a Garry's Mod Server, ok so we have a box saying Rules, and when we go to place a website INSIDE OF THAT BOX, it shows exactly this:

http://cloud-4.steamusercontent.com/ugc/37489242708029141/B4E51CC2F089F13DF25AA8F4F3E9BF7A07619427/

As you can see, it shows a box with the HTML5 coding, not sure if I can place:
http://www.sparkperp.com/Rules/index.html on that box.

I would like to know how to do that, if it's possible.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please give your code in the future. Since I'm unable to view your code I'm limited in how much I can help, but I will try my best anyway!

You need to use the HTML vgui element `vgui.Create("HTML")` and use `:OpenURL(weblink)` on it. You can also use `:SetHTML(htmlstring)` if required. You should get the idea from the below code block:

```
local MOTD = vgui.Create( "HTML", parent )
MOTD:OpenURL("http://www.sparkperp.com/Rules/index.html")
```

If you can't get it working, update your question with your code and I'll be able to help further.